# invalid client - google-auth-library even when client id is correct

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-auth-library

I'm using `google-auth-library` in nodejs

Everything was working fine. until for some reason my one of the domain is down. `api.example1.com`

and in google console the redirect uri was ->
`https://api.example1.com/google/cb` there was nothing special in that route since I'm already getting the

`auth_code` from client like -> React, Android

```
import { useGoogleLogin } from "@react-oauth/google";
```

so I've just created another server with same code on the `api.example2.com` and I've also added this in the authorized redirect urls.

but unfortunately. it giving error even though

`CLIENT_ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET` are correct.

This is Error I  Got

```
{
"error": "invalid_client",
"error_description": "Unauthorized"
}
```

```
const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client({
  clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET_ID,
  redirectUri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI,
});
```

Usage

```
const { tokens } = await oAuth2Client.getToken(code);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over Confidence is not a good thing.

You may think that every credential is valid but that is not the case.

In my case my `CLIENT_SECRET` was different.

so double check if possible triple check every credential for this error.
`invalid_client`

```json
{
  "error": "invalid_client",
  "error_description": "Unauthorized"
}
```